# Liferay: Set VIEW permission to a DLFileEntry to users of a site

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is it possible to set VIEW only permission to a single document library file (DLFileEntry) to the users of a different site.

Example : DocumentA exists in SiteA and I want to set view permissions to all the users of SITEB only to this document.

Thanks for reading.

-Mike

Answer (score 2):

You'll need some kind of indirection: Permissions in Liferay are handled through roles (teams behave as roles as well), not by other arbitrary groups of users. If you assign all the users to a user group and make that user group member of the site in question, as well as assign them to a role that you create for this purpose.

Comment: What about "permissions.user.check.algorithm" property? Liferay staff suggest it could be possible to assign permission directly to user. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/12273211

Comment: Not my favourite: I don't know how long the antiquated algorithms will be supported or contained. They don't scale well and are not in widespread use. If you really need a custom non-role based permission on downloads, I'd rather recommend to implement it yourself, in a custom portlet that contains your algorithm. This portlet bypasses Liferay's permission checks, utilizing the DL*LocalService API. That's probably far more maintainable than relying on an ancient permission check algorithm.